# Show DIV submenu dropdown when hovering

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I am trying to create a very simple hover/drop menu using DIVs, no UL/LI.
My current code shows the menu with 3 options, but what I need is to have a submenu under Link 2.
Here is my current code.

```css
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 0px;
        font-size: 12px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      margin-top:200px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 30px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
        bottom: 100%;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    .subdiv {
        display:none;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .subdiv {
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">^</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I would like to do is this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">^</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">SubLink 1</a>
        </div>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where the SubLink 1 item shows up when you hover over Link 2, but everything I have tried doesn't work, so I'm hoping someone else can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with the following, all you need to do is to set a div (here submenu_holder) that contains the submenu and the link to hover, the next step is straightforward, as it is the same process with submenu_holder than with dropdown.

```css
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 0px;
        font-size: 12px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      margin-top:200px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 30px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
        bottom: 100%;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    .subdiv {
        display:none;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .subdiv {
        display:block;
    }

.submenu {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:60px;
  top:0px;
}

.submenu_holder:hover .submenu {
  display:block;
}

.submenu_holder {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">^</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <div class="submenu_holder">
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#">SubLink 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues in your code.

For starters, your classnames for the submenu didn't correspond.

Below, I've wrapped the content of the submenu *within* Link 2. You will need to make further adjustments to make the hover effect smoother...

```css
body {
  /* for demo purposes */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* changed because the target was infuriatingly small for demo */
  padding: 1em;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover,
.submenu:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  bottom: 100%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.submenu {
  padding: 12px 16px;
}

.submenu-content {
  display: none;
}

.submenu-content a {
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.submenu:hover .submenu-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">^</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
What I would like to do is this:

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">^</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <div class="submenu">Link 2
      <div class="submenu-content">
        <a href="#">SubLink 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you got a div with an href ;), same method as mine, but without the "side" menu

Comment: @Neil well spotted, I've removed that.. thanks! Yes, same method, only way to do it really :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I ended up using and works best for my situation:

```
<style>

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    bottom: 100%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.subdiv {
    display:none;
}

.dropdown:hover .subdiv {
    display:block;
}

.submenu {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  left:86px;
  top:0px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.submenu_holder:hover .submenu {
  display:block;
}

.submenu_holder {
  position:relative;
}

</style>


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">^</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <div class="submenu_holder">
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <div class="submenu">
        <a href="#">SubLink 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```