# Div nested in an Anchor is treated as a sibling

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create an anchor that would popup a div with anchor children when hovered. In order to achieve that, I created something like this:

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dropdown</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="dropdown" href="#">
    <span>Community</span>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
    </div>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

However, it failed to work.

While trying to find a solution, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984685/show-div-submenu-dropdown-when-hovering) similar issue, where it was suggested to create a div wrapper around the root anchor, and use that as the target of :hover. However, I wanted to keep looking into it, in order to understand why the original code would not work. After some trial and error, I discovered that:

**1.** Using any type (at least from those I tried) other than anchor as children of .dropdown-content made the above code work as intended. However, as soon as an anchor child is inserted into .dropdown-content, it stops working again. So this works:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <p href="contact.html">Contact</p>
  <p href="faq.html">FAQ</p>
</div>
```

While this does not:

```
<div class="dropdown-content">
  <p href="contact.html">Contact</p>
  <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
</div>
```

**2.** The .dropdown-content can be displayed properly with anchor children, if the *descendant selector* is replaced by an *adjacent sibling combinator*. That is, doing this:

```
.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

instead of this:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

effectively solves the original issue.

Having tested this in various browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11), I can safely assume that this is not a browser-specific bug. However, this has led me to the following questions:

1. It may be cross-browser compliant, but is it normal behavior? That is, is it stated or implied somewhere (e.g. [W3C](https://www.w3.org/)) that this is how anchors should work? I searched various sources, but I could not find an answer.
2. If it is a normal behavior, why is .dropdown-content treated as a sibling when it contains an anchor element, whereas it is treated as a child without one.
3. Is it possible to make .dropdown-content (or a div in general) have consistent behavior (i.e. treat nested elements as children), regardless of its parent and child elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That is, is it stated or implied somewhere (e.g. W3C) that this is how anchors should work?

See [the a element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) which says "Content model:
Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants."

You cannot put an anchor inside another anchor.

> If it is a normal behavior, why is .dropdown-content treated as a sibling when it contains an anchor element, whereas it is treated as a child without one.

Browsers rearrange the DOM to try to make it valid. You can see the resulting structure using the developer tools in your browser.

> Is it possible to make .dropdown-content (or a div in general) have consistent behavior (i.e. treat nested elements as children), regardless of its parent and child elements?

It does … the problem is that your attempt to make an `a` a descendant of another `a` is failing in the first place.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I thought it would be legal to have an anchor inside another one if it was a grandchild, but your source clearly states that there must be no interactive _descendant_, which is good to know. Thanks for the help!